# Changing a button's background after a few seconds

Tags: java, android

I'd like to change to color of my button after a few seconds. I've made a quiz app, and when you answer the question right, the button will turn green, and when you answer the question wrong it will turn red. Now I've created this, but it doesn't work because it gives this error for the Runnable: `

> Class: Anonymous class derived from Runnable must either be declared
>   abstract or implement abstract method `run()` in Runnable.

So what is wrong here?

```
if (mQuestionNumber == QuestionLibrary.mQuestionsFrankrijk.length) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(QuizActivityFrankrijk.this, 
QuizResultaat.class);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putInt("finalScore", mScoreFrankrijk);
                    i.putExtras(bundle);
                    QuizActivityFrankrijk.this.finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                } else {

                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_fout);
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivityFrankrijk.this, "Fout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        public void run(View view) {
                            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_bg_rounded_corners);
                            updateQuestion();
                        }
                    }, 10000);
                    updateQuestion();

                }
```

Comment: Why exactly do you need time based updates? isnt the color change triggered after the check ?

Comment: try handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

Comment: And remove that view in your run method which you are taking as parameter.

Comment: Why do you want to wait a few seconds?? Suspense? Imo it should trigger when you click, otherwise the app will feel unresponsive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `@Override` annotation on `run` method and remove `View` object from arguments.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_bg_rounded_corners);
                updateQuestion();

            }
        }, 10000);
```

Comment: if your problem is solved consider acceptation the answer. Thanks!

Comment: When I do that the view of view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_bg_rounded_corn‌​‌​ers) gives the following error: "Variable 'view' is accessed from within inner class , needs to be declared final.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() { //Remove the argument
                            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_bg_rounded_corners);
                            updateQuestion();
                        }
                    }, 10000);
```

The problem is, you are not overriding the right `run()` method. 
The method provided by `Runnable` class requires you to override no-argument method.

Comment: When I do that the view of view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_bg_rounded_corners) gives the following error: "Variable 'view' is accessed from within inner class , needs to be declared final.

Comment: Declare `view` as global object and then you can access it in `run()`

Comment: Then declare your view final. Just add keyword final to your View view